# Adding a table that can be edited in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface

I know this might be a ridiculous question that kind of defeats the purpose of a userform but I have a large userform that I would like to use to avoid the user from having to interact with the sheets.

Here goes...

I would like to add a table that you can edit in the userform which is linked to cells in a certain sheet. As you can see in the image below, each row has an individual name which has to be entered by the user manually.

what I was going to do was create a number of textboxes in the location column and use the lists tool for the other two columns (Probe ID and location number) that you can see in the picture. However, when I do this it is impossible to get the textboxes to line up and the code would be quite long winded. Hence why I am looking for something that can simplfy the task.

I have looked around online but all I have found is the following which can't be edited in the userform, but it does have the beginings of what I would be looking for.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/scrollable-table-in-a-userform-4-columns-rows.89215/

Any constructive suggestions welcome!

[image]